# Rails has_one / belongs_to not saving parent id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, nested-attributes, simple-form

I have 2 models, Response and Entry.

```
Response has_one Entry
Entry belongs_to Response
```

*(Trying to do this on the show view of a Response)*

In the controller action for Show I have:

```
@response = Response.find(params[:id])
@entry = @response.build_entry(:response_id => @response.id)
```

*Also tried just `@response.build_entry`*

Using simple_form gem, and simple_form_for @entry creates the entry, but does not save the parent (response) id in the entry record.

The only way I have accomplished this is to add a hidden field to the form, which I don't really want to do...

Answer (score 1):

Ref [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_one-association-reference)

Remove `:response_id => @response.id` from `build`

```
@response = Response.find(params[:id])
@entry = @response.build_entry
@response.save
```

Comment: Problem is I don't want to save the record before the form is submitted and validated...

Comment: Yes, thats why i you should used build if any validation of the `response` & `entry` get failed it will not save the other data. i.e. this will confirm you that there will be no `response` with out `entry` and vice-versa

Comment: Ok but doing that now shows validation error messages when viewing the response page (i.e. the form) before anything is submitted, then after submission, I still have the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

Salil's code is correct. I think you should revise your approach and move data validation from the controller to the model.

Comment: I don't understand, my validation (i.e. presence and uniqueness) is in the model :(

Comment: Ok. You said that you "don't want to save the record before the form is submitted and validated". When validation in the model fails, data doesn't get saved, so why not try saving, at least?

Comment: I did, and that led me to me third comment. The problem was when I was calling save, it was displaying the validation messages before submission

Comment: Just a thought: can this RailsCasts episode help fixing your validation issues? http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes-revised?view=asciicast